# How to visualize function output

Tags: r

I cannot understand how to visualize this function on R.

Can you please help me to understand this problem?

```
Form_CharSizePorts2 <- function(main, size, var, wght, ret) { # streamlined version
  # forms 2x3 (size x specificed-characteristc) and forms the 6 portfolios
  # variable broken by 30-70 percentiles, size broken up at 50 percentile (breakpoints uses NYSE data only)
  # requires Date and exchcd
  # outputs portfolio returns for each period,
  
  main.cln <- main %>%
    select(Date, PERMNO, exchcd, !!size, !!var, !!wght, !!ret)
  
  Bkpts.NYSE <- main.cln %>% # create size and var breakpoints based on NYSE stocks only
    filter(exchcd == 1) %>% # NYSE exchange
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarize(var.P70 = quantile(!!var, probs=.7, na.rm=TRUE),
              var.P30 = quantile(!!var, probs=.3, na.rm=TRUE),
              size.Med = quantile(!!size, probs=.5, na.rm=TRUE))
# calculate size and var portfolio returns
  main.rank <- main.cln %>%
    merge(Bkpts.NYSE, by="Date", all.x=TRUE) %>%
    mutate(Size = ifelse(!!size<size.Med, "Small", "Big"),
           Var = ifelse(!!var<var.P30, "Low", ifelse(!!var>var.P70, "High", "Neutral")),
           Port = paste(Size, Var, sep="."))
  
  Ret <- main.rank %>% # name 2 x 3 size-var portfolios
    group_by(Date, Port) %>%
    summarize(ret.port = weighted.mean(!!ret, !!wght, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% # calc value-weighted returns
    spread(Port, ret.port) %>% # transpose portfolios expressed as rows into seperate columns
    mutate(Small = (Small.High + Small.Neutral + Small.Low)/3,
           Big = (Big.High + Big.Neutral + Big.Low)/3,
           SMB = Small - Big,
           High = (Small.High + Big.High)/2,
           Low = (Small.Low + Big.Low)/2,
           HML = High - Low)
  
  returnValue(Ret)
}
```

Is there any way to get the outputs of this function?

Comment: Hello, I think that you should change the !!var call to {{ var }}  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection. It might cause problems in your functions.

Comment: Do you have inputs for the function? Maybe an example of how it is called?

Comment: @GregorThomas Hi, thanks for the reply, this is the link: drive.google.com/file/d/1_7SbVmnw7yDp6Q9_4_LKvnB8JTwVv7lq/view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: People will be much more likely to help if you can make the question self-contained - putting a small subset of copy/pasteable data in the question (`dput()` is good for this), as well as showing the code of how you are calling the function. Make things clear and easy for people to help you.